# PowerShell Delete lines from output

Tags: powershell

I am running the following command part of a script in powershell, and need to get rid of the return carriages or white lines and brackets.

Original execution and output:

grpcurl -d '{ "service": "service1" }' -H "authorization: key key"  service1.env.domain.net:port grpc.health.v1.Health/Check

> {

> "status": "SERVING"

> }

Now I am able to remove the brackets..

Original execution and output:

grpcurl -d '{ "service": "service1" }' -H "authorization: key key"  service1.env.domain.net:port grpc.health.v1.Health/Check | Select-String   "status"

> 

> "status": "SERVING"

> 

Now the question, how can I get this output ??

> **"status": "SERVING"**

Comment: Your `grpcurl` command is outputting a Json, why not treat as such instead of "just strings" and use `ConvertFrom-Json` ?

Comment: Is not working for me :(

ConvertFrom-Json : Primitivo JSON no válido: "SERVING".

       $pp = $response -join "" | ConvertFrom-Json
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: That's odd, your output seems like a perfectly valid json. Well maybe this works `(grpcurl -d '{ "service": "service1" }' -H "authorization: key key" service1.env.domain.net:port grpc.health.v1.Health/Check | Select-String "status").Trim()`

Comment: but the command is not working inside the (). Just need a way to remove the two lines between the "SERVING" from the output when I run a grpcurl.

Comment: Please show us the **entire** output from the `grpcurl` command. As @SantiagoSquarzon says, it looks like JSON and therefore you should be able to convert it to objects from whick you can simply 'pick' the properties

Comment: maybe it is a misunderstanding, it fails in the script, if I run the grpcurl alone

Comment: grpcurl -d '{ \"service\": \"service\" }' -H "authorization: token  token"  name.env.domain.net:443 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check  | ConvertFrom-Json

`status
------
SERVING`

Comment: so it`s working but I need just this output (no lines or blank spaces, carriage returns, etc,,,) just plain text:

`SERVING`